# Why do the main site stats say "99% answered"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Under "Unanswered", it shows 0 questions are unanswered, so shouldn't it be 100%? Are you using other numbers I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lag.

The stats and the Unanswered query can at any point in time be lagged, one or the other could be out of date. As I loaded the Unanswered just now, there were 2 questions on it showing with zero answers. By the time I clicked through to one of them, it had an answer.

It's just how the internet works: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=eventual+consistency

Comment: Aah, this makes sense.  Good to know, thanks!